# Running a report showing current record from subform

Tags: ms-access

firstly, my database is using a navigation form which has tabs down the side to allow the user to navigate through the forms and then all the forms within this have sub forms.

Now the issue I have is that I'm trying to run a report using a macro and the where condition so that it only shows the current record. If I view the form on its own (not through the navigation form) the button works perfectly (happy days) but when I use it through the navigation form (which is how the user will be using it) it asks me to enter the ID for the record first. Technically the report will still run but it relies on the user entering the correct ID.

this is my where condition: `[ChildID]=[Forms]![frmMealChoice]![ChildID]` is there a way to navigate to a subform in the where condition?

Sorry if that doesn't make much sense but I can't think of a better way of explaining it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out about 2mins after I posted... typical! in case anyone else is interested this is my amended where condition [ChildID]=[Forms]![FrmMainNavigation]![NavigationSubform]![ChildID]  I assumed that I needed to put the name of the actual subform... i was wrong haha

Comment: is there a way of closing this question or should i just delete it?

Comment: You can post and answer your self and accept it to show it is resolved. That's the best way to leave this info up for someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in the comments I figured out where I went almost instantly after posting the question. So for anyone interested here is my ammeded where condition;
    [ChildID]=[Forms]![FrmMainNavigation]![NavigationSubform]![ChildID]